# Thumbnail from Video VLC VS FFMPEG

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ffmpeg, vlc

I am uploading videos to SQL SERVER SQL database using MVC. So far I can programmatically download unprocessed videos to my Computer process them *eg convert to desired format/generate thumbnails/ etc etc and reupload the videos.* I am using `VLC Command Line` [*I know this might get me thumbs down but hey it works.*] and a custom program. I read a lot about FFMPEG but most examples are in `PHP` and I am yet to come across any MVC example. I am thinking of transitioning to `FFMPEG` but want to ask people if the right place for `FFMPEG` is on the SERVER or on a PC? And can you point me to any examples/tutorials of `FFMPEG` in `MVC/ASP`.

Comment: How is using FFMPEG with command line commands any different than VLC? Or do you mean you aren't using VLC in your web application yet? Either way, you could research how to execute command-lines in ASP.NET MVC... doesn't need to be FFMPEG specific.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Vlc is not on the server its on my home computer so the Server is free to do what it does best i.e exchange data and a dedicated computer does the video processing. Ffmpeg looks promising but I dont know where should I process the video on server or on my computer i.e a dedicated video processing machine.

Comment: If you can afford a dedicated server that does nothing but process video, then that would be better than doing it on your web server.